# Unable to run linked in demo due to locked environment

Tags: r, httr

I can't run the linked in demo in httr due to an error message about being unable to add variables to a locked environment. The specific piece of code, is where Hadley has to extend Token2.0 in order to accommodate LI's nonstandard oauth2

```
TokenLinkedIn <- setRefClass("TokenLinkedIn", contains = "Token2.0",
                         methods = list(
                             sign = function(method, url) {
                                 url <- parse_url(url)
                                 url$query$oauth2_access_token <- credentials$access_token
                                 list(url = build_url(url), config = config())
                             }
                         ), where = asNamespace("httr")
)
```

The error message is:
Error in assign(mname, def, where):
  cannot add bindings to a locked environment

System:
MAC OS Mavericks
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
httr version 0.3

I have not been able to find a successful solution yet

Comment: What if you just take out the `, where = asNamespace("httr")`? You can try setting `environment(TokenLinkedIn)<-asNamespace("httr")` immediately after instead.

Comment: Making that change lead to another error:  Error in load_from_cache() : could not find function "fetch_cached_token"

Comment: And that was after the environment assignment? I tried to test but i don't have a secret Linked In key.

Comment: Yes. I have noted this issue in github where hadley maintains the package. I'm likely making a schoolboy error somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an issue due to changes in the package environment of R 3.0.3 in that : "The namespace environments of packages with namespaces are locked when loaded."

https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/113#issuecomment-48068410